# windows phone 8.1 2d drawing c#

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I have to make an app with 2d drawing for Windows RT. I don't know how can achieve that. Drawing with xaml is not a option, because I have to draw it at run time, and the content of graphic will varies. I am looking for something like android's View and it's  onDraw() method, Is that possible?

Comment: could you explain with some code?

Comment: You'll probably need the `WriteableBitmap`  Or, maybe Win2D if that works in this scenario.

Comment: WritableBitmap isn't a option because the elements must be animated (translated, rotated faded).